# Кто такие афей и деист у Пушкина

Tags: лексика

> И скромно ты внимал
>   За чашей медленной афею иль деисту,
>   Как любопытный скиф афинскому софисту.

Вопрос-то вот в чём: афей и деист — это атеист и боговерец? Или Александр обыграл «чаша медленная кофе или чая»?

Answer (score 4):

Афей (атей) — да, атеист.
Деист (от деус — двойственный) — представитель учения деизма, признающего Бога как первопричину всего сущего, но отвергающего дальнейшее его влияние на развитие мира. 
Деизм, таким образом, - двойственный идеалистическо-материалистический подход.
Оба в общем-то - представители течений, противостоящих истинному верованию.

По поводу "кофе или чая" — не понял, что вы имели в виду. 
Соль "шутки" в бесполезности "внимания" дикого скифа просвещенному философствующему афинянину. И адресат (не помню навскидку, кто это, посмотрю позже) столь же бесполезно тратит время.
+
Баратынского убрал (не туда посмотрел). Адресат - Юсупов, спасибо Людмиле. 
Вот насчет Дидро - сомнения одолевают.

Нашел вот одну работу, пока не сообразил, кто автор, но похоже, Людмила информацию оттуда черпала.
http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=Kw5ngaazjII%3D&tabid=10183

Некоторые сомнения в том, что назвав личность "атея", авторы прошли мимо деиста. Как-то совсем не по-пушкински, ставить в один ряд реальную фигуру и абстрактную.

А история-то разматывается, спасибо Людмиле.
Вот первоисточник большинства сведений (включая указания на Тынянова).
http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=ZcaJ1VDJyOc%3D&tabid=10396
Автора не знаю совершенно, большинство фактов для меня и подавно не знакомы, проверять всё - это труд для меня непосильный. Ну пусть скиф будет Анахарсисом. Личность, вопреки источникам, - вполне историческая.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81

Но вот что интересно. Из статьи следует, что Анахарсис встречался с афинским политиком и поэтом Солоном. Но фокус в том, что Солон не был софистом, он вообще философом не был. Софистом из Афин был, как верно сказали, Платон (и то с большой натяжкой), но он родился век спустя после смерти Анахарсиса. 
Нестыковочка.

Comment: Все правильно, но не до конца. У философа имяч есть. Афинский софист - это Платон.  Видимо, дикий скиф - тоже кто-то из исторических личностей, известных Пушкину и Баратынскому. Может быть, даже их круга. .

Comment: @Иванов7-й возможно и Платон. Я не заострялся на персоналиях, Вопрос-то был о значении слов. Но вот с подачи Людмилы начал думать об исторических личностях.

Comment: Всё хорошо и познавательно, спасибо. Но для Пушкина  вставить в строку после "чтителя промысла", "скептика", "безбожника" ещё и обсуждаемые "афею иль деисту" как-то слишком расточительно. И потом "за чашей медленной"... Не " с сигарой длинною" или "в зерцало глядючи".

Answer (score 3):

Это послание "К вельможе". Вельможа - князь Юсупов. Афей, "безбожник"- Дидро, автор «Мыслей об объяснении природы» (1754). Краткая характеристика Дидро: «То чтитель промысла, то скептик, то безбожник» — намечает основные вехи мировоззренческой эволюции вождя энциклопедистов — от «Философских мыслей» и «Прогулок скептика» к позднейшему атеизму.  Юсупов видит позднего Дидро, которого Пушкин несколькими годами позднее назовет «пылким» и «самым ревностным» «апостолом» Вольтера  и даже «фанатиком». В послании не произнесено это слово, но понятие уже есть. «Дидерот» на «шатком треножнике», бросающий парик и проповедующий «в восторге», закрыв глаза, ассоциативно связан с пифией, вещающей в экстазе. Юсупов внимает «афею» и «деисту», сохраняя скептическую умеренность, но не споря и не опровергая, скорее учась. Это пишется в разгар антипросветительской кампании в литературе.

Comment: Людмила, А "деист" тогда кто?

Comment: Похоже, это образ синкретичный. Многие западные ученые являются деистами – они признают Божественное начало мира, при этом отлично знают естественные законы. Деизм- стремление человека преодолеть чувство зависимости от сверхъестественных сил. Известными деистами были  Вольтер и Жан-Жак Руссо. С обоими Юсупов встречался.

Comment: «Как любопытный скиф афинскому софисту»."Любопытный скиф"– Анахарсис, молодой скиф, путешествующий по Греции, герой «Путешествия» Бартелеми, он «был у Пушкина общим образцом русского путешественника по Западу» (Ю.Тынянов). Есть отсылки и к вольтеровскому стихотворению вплоть до эпитета «любопытный» — curieux, Карамзин называл себя молодым скифом К. в «Письмах русского путешественника»(он посетил Францию в канун революции). Так что тоже синкретичный образ

Answer (score 2):

"К вельможе" – послание к князю Николаю Борисовичу Юсупову (1751—1831),одному из последних деятелей XVIII в., рассказы которых любил слушать Пушкин. Вызвано приглашением Юсупова посетить его в его подмосковном имении Архангельском.

**Ученье делалось на время твой кумир:**
Уединялся ты. За твой суровый пир
**То чтитель промысла, то скептик, то безбожник,**
Садился Дидерот на шаткий свой треножник,
Бросал парик, глаза в восторге закрывал
И проповедывал. И скромно ты внимал
За чашей медленной **афею иль деисту,**
Как любопытный скиф афинскому софисту.

Слово афей от  латинского "ateos" – безбожник, атеист.

**Афей или деист** – речь идет о Дидро, который, как и многие  ученые того времени, особенно  воспитанные в христианском духе, мог изначально иметь взгляды **деистов.** (Деисты считали, что творец лишь запустил мир, дал ему законы, а дальше устранился и наблюдает, а мир существует независимо).

Дидро, вероятно,  "проповедовал" Юсупову взгляды обоих направлений, **то есть был то афеем, то деистом.** **Другой вариант:** собеседнику трудно было понять, афей или деист перед ним; или "любопытному скифу" трудно было разобраться, чем эти философские направления  вообще отличаются друг от друга (действительно, что-то **вроде чая или кофе**).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) **Немного истории: как они (Дидро и Юсупов) познакомились**

Летом 1774 года Юсупов отправился в Лейден прослушать в тамошнем университете курс наук.  В Лейдене Николай Борисович пробыл с середины июля 1774 по февраль или начало марта 1776 года. Никита Иванович Панин дал Юсупову рекомендательное письмо к русскому посланнику в Гааге князю Дмитрию Алексеевичу Голицыну (1734–1803), который, в свою очередь, рекомендовал князя в Лейденский университет, куда без протекции даже с деньгами попасть оказалось не так-то просто. **Князь Голицын в эти дни, в июле 1774 года, принимал в своем гаагском доме возвратившегося из Петербурга знаменитого французского философа Дени Дидро**, с которым они были дружны. **Юсупова представили гостю.** По всей видимости, представление это не ограничилось лишь светскими любезностями — разговор с юным русским князем, отличавшимся остротой ума, наверняка оказался интересен знаменитому философу.

О Юсупове: Князь Юсупов, который передаст Вам это письмо, является русским господином… Не буду повторять то, что я уже имел честь Вам сказать **о широте и глубине его обширных знаний,** особенно в греческом языке… **Это один из самых выдающихся людей Европы»**[103].

[ГЛАВА 8 ИЗ ЖИЗНИ ЛЕЙДЕНСКОГО СТУДЕНТА | bookitut.ru](http://bookitut.ru/Knyazj-Nikolaj-Borisovich-Yusupov-Veljmozha-diplomat-kollekczioner.10.html)

**2) О любопытном скифе**

Скифия как **географическое понятие, охватывающее всю Восточную Европу**, перешло из античности в средневековую и новую литературу.  Немалый вклад в прославление не испорченных цивилизацией скифов внесли греческие философы, которые идеализировали варварские народы, живущие якобы в согласии с природой. Наиболее ярко тенденция идеализации скифов проступает в серии сначала фольклорных, а затем литературных **новелл об Анахарсисе, мудром скифе, посетившем Элладу в VI в..**

В 1788 г. в Париже вышел **роман аббата Жан Жака Бартелеме «Путешествие младшего Анахарсиса в Грецию»**. Он имел огромный успех и выдержал несколько изданий. В романе рассказывалось, как в IV в. молодой скиф Анахарсис отправился в Грецию для получения образования. **Путешествие младшего Анахарсиса целиком придумано Бартелеме,** но идею о поездке скифа в Грецию с целью обучения аббат почерпнул у античных авторов. **Герой романа шел по стопам своего предка и тезки, жившего на два столетия раньше.**

В библиотеке А. С. Пушкина был роман Бартелеме. Под его впечатлением поэт в стихотворении «К вельможе» **сравнил с Анахарсисом князя Юсупова,** путешествовавшего по Европе и встречавшегося там с многими выдающимися философами и писателями.

[Формирование стереотипов в изображении скифов | sno.pro1.ru](http://www.sno.pro1.ru/lib/skrzhinskaya2/11.htm)